# Facebook plugin don't show right when user is logged as a page

Tags: facebook, plugins, authentication

I have noticed that Facebook plugin don't show right when user is logged as a page.
The plugin shows a message that sound like "Back to USER to use this plugin".

I want to show the plugin only if my visitor is a USER (not a page or app).

I implemented the code according to the specifications of facebook, but I can not find the php or javascript snippets that allows me to create this filter.

Can someone help me? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FB.api({ 
    method: 'fql.query',
    query: 'SELECT type FROM profile WHERE username IN (SELECT username FROM user WHERE uid=me())'
    }, 
    function(response) {
        (response.type == 'user') ? $('#fb_elem_id_here').css('display', 'inline-block') : $('#fb_elem_id_here').css('display', 'none');
    });
```

[facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook)[fql](/questions/tagged/fql)[jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)[fb.api](/questions/tagged/fb.api)[fql.query](/questions/tagged/fql.query)

Comment: I think
`(response.type = 'user') ? ...`
should be
`(response.type == 'user') ? ...`
but `response.type` is always `undefined`.

The problem still exists:
[link](http://www.claudioitaliano.com)

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround:

`FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) { **DO_SOMETHING** })`

only **DO_SOMETHING** if user is logged as a USER or when user is no logged at all, than you can filter your action.

The initial suggestion does not work.
Context is of simple web browsing: user never connect to the FB app.
FB information (I think) come from browser cookies.